# Inverse function of $x+\ln(x)$

Tags: functions

How can I find the inverse function of $$f(x)=x+\ln(x).$$
This function has an inverse function (I can prove it) but I couldn't find it.
Help please!

Comment: Start by identifying the domain and range of $f(x)$.  What do you expect to find in the way of an inverse of $f(x)$?

Comment: The inverse function of $f$ is just that; you can't express it in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 13):

$y=x+lnx$

$y=ln(e^x)+ln(x)$

$y=ln(xe^x)$

$e^y=xe^x$

Here, you can use the [Lambert W Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications)

$x=W(e^y)$